# The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 websites; One is for Public and other for admin.These boith are seperate websites.
theSite.dll is for public and theSiteCMS for admin.

The code below is from AdminSite i.e theSiteCMS.This site also contains theSite.dll reference which also has same member functions Html.ActiveLinkImage.

I doubt that I am not able to isolate these call ;hence the error.
Kindly suggest the right way.

**Code theSiteCMS(admin site)**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<theSiteCMS.Helpers.Pagination<theSiteCMS.Models.Article>>"%>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Articles Management
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function goToPage(pageIndex) {
            $("#page").val(pageIndex);
            $('#SearchForm').submit();
        }

        function sortField(fld, sortDirection) {
            $("#sort_field").val(fld);
            $("#sort_dir").val(sortDirection);
            $('#SearchForm').submit();
            return false;
        }     
    </script>
    <h2>Articles Management</h2>
    <% string[] articles_status = { "Draft", "Submitted", "Published", "Archived", "Deleted" }; %>
    <% var _gridState = (theSiteCMS.Controllers.ArticlesController.GridState)ViewData["GridState"];
       var queryCollection = new { 
                    sort_field= _gridState.sort.field
                    ,sort_dir = (_gridState.sort.direction == theSiteCMS.Controllers.AppController.SortDirection.Descending) ? "desc" : "asc"
                    ,status = _gridState.status
                    ,keyword = _gridState.keyword
                    ,username = _gridState.username
                    ,section_id = _gridState.section_id
                    ,category_id = _gridState.category_id
                    ,page = _gridState.page
       };
    %>
    <%Html.BeginForm("index", "Articles", FormMethod.Post, new { id="SearchForm"}); %>   
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td width="16%">Status</td>
            <td width="16%">Section</td>
            <td width="16%">Category</td>
            <!--td width="16%">Published</td-->
            <td width="16%">User</td>
            <td width="16%">Keyword</td>
            <td width="4%">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><%= Html.DropDownList("status", theSiteCMS.Controllers.ArticlesController.ArticleStatusList(_gridState.status), "ALL", new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })%></td>
        <td><%= Html.DropDownList("section_id", theSiteCMS.Controllers.SectionsController.SectionsList(_gridState.section_id), "--select all--", new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })%></td>
        <td><%= Html.DropDownList("category_id", theSiteCMS.Controllers.SectionsController.CategoriesList(_gridState.section_id, _gridState.category_id), "--select all--", new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })%></td>
        <!--td><%/* Html.jQuery().DatePicker()
                    .Name("publish_at")
                    .DateFormat("mm-dd-yy")
                    .NavigationAsDateFormat(true)
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style="width:100px"})
                    .Render();*/ %></td-->
        <td><%= Html.TextBox("username", _gridState.username, new { style = "width:100px" })%></td>
        <td><%= Html.TextBox("keyword", _gridState.keyword, new { style="width:100px"})%></td>
        <td width="15%"><input type="submit" value="find" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <%=Html.Hidden("sort_dir", _gridState.sort.direction == theSiteCMS.Controllers.AppController.SortDirection.Descending?"desc":"asc") %>
    <%=Html.Hidden("sort_field", _gridState.sort.field) %>

    <%=Html.Hidden("page", _gridState.page) %>
   <%Html.EndForm(); %>


   <hr />

    <table width ="100%">
    <caption><%= ViewData["Message"] %></caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Action</th>
           <th><%= Html.ActionLink("Title", "Index", new { action="Index"}, new { @class = Html.GetSortCssClass(_gridState.sort, "title"), onclick = "return sortField('title','asc');" })%></th>
            <th><%= Html.ActionLink("Author", "Index", new { action="Index"}, new { @class = Html.GetSortCssClass(_gridState.sort, "user_id"), onclick = "sortField('user_id','asc');return false;" })%></th>
            <th><%= Html.ActionLink("Date", "Index", new { action="Index"}, new { @class = Html.GetSortCssClass(_gridState.sort, "publish_at"), onclick = "sortField('publish_at','asc');return false;" })%></th> 
            <th><%= Html.ActionLink("Status", "Index", new { action="Index"}, new { @class = Html.GetSortCssClass(_gridState.sort, "status"), onclick = "sortField('status','asc');return false;" })%></th>           
            <th>
                Comments
            </th>
            <th>
                View count
            </th>
        </tr>

    <% foreach (var item in Model)
       { %>

        <tr>
            <td width="100">
                <%=Html.ActionLinkImage("Edit", Url.Content("~/images/icons/pencil.png"), "Edit", new { action = "Edit", id = item.id }, new { title = "Edit" })%>
                <%=Html.ActionLinkImage("View", Url.Content("~/images/icons/eye.png"), "Details", new { action = "Details", id = item.id }, new { title = "View" })%><br />
                <% if (item.status ==0){ //draft%>
                    <%=Html.Image("~/images/icons/application_edit.png", new {@class="disabled"}) %>
                <%} else {%>
                    <%=Html.ActionLinkImage("Draft", Url.Content("~/images/icons/application_edit.png"), "changeStatus", new { action = "changeStatus", id = item.id, s = 0 }, new { title="Draft"})%>
                <%} %> 

                <% if (item.status ==1){ //submit%>
                    <%=Html.Image("~/images/icons/application_go.png", new {@class="disabled"}) %>
                <%} else {%>
                    <%=Html.ActionLinkImage("Draft", Url.Content("~/images/icons/application_go.png"), "changeStatus", new { action = "changeStatus", id = item.id, s = 1 }, new { title = "Submit" })%>
                <%} %> 
                <% if (item.status ==2){ //publish %>
                    <%=Html.Image("~/images/icons/accept.png", new {@class="disabled"}) %>
                <%} else {%>
                    <%=Html.ActionLinkImage("Publish", Url.Content("~/images/icons/accept.png"), "changeStatus", new { action = "changeStatus", id = item.id, s = 2 }, new { title = "Publish" })%>
                <%} %>                                  
                <% if (item.status ==3){ //archive %>
                    <%=Html.Image("~/images/icons/compress.png", new {@class="disabled"}) %>
                <%} else {%>
                    <%=Html.ActionLinkImage("Archive", Url.Content("~/images/icons/compress.png"), "changeStatus", new { action = "changeStatus", id = item.id, s = 3 }, new { title = "Archive" })%>
                <%} %>
                <% if (item.status ==4){ //deleted %>
                    <%=Html.Image("~/images/icons/application_delete.png", new {@class="disabled"}) %>
                <%} else {%>
                    <%=Html.ActionLinkImage("Archive", Url.Content("~/images/icons/application_delete.png"), "changeStatus", new { action = "changeStatus", id = item.id, s = 4 }, new { title = "Delete" })%>
                <%} %>                     
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.Encode(item.title)%><br/>
                <%= Html.Encode(item.Category.Section.title)%> , <%= Html.Encode(item.Category.title)%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.Encode(item.User.username)%>
            </td>

            <td>
                <%= Html.Encode(String.Format("{0:g}", item.publish_at))%>
            </td>

            <td>
                <%= Html.Encode(articles_status[item.status])%>
            </td>
            <td>                
                <%= Html.Encode(item.Comments.Count())%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.Encode(item.viewcount)%>
            </td>

        </tr>

    <% } %>

    </table>

    <div class="pagination">
        <% if (Model.HasPreviousPage)
           { %>
            <%= Html.RouteLink("previous",
                               "Default",
                               new { page = (Model.PageIndex - 1) })%>

        <% }
           else
           { %>
           previous
        <%} %>
         | 
        <% if (Model.HasNextPage)
           { %>

            <%= Html.RouteLink("next",
                               "Default",
                               new { page = (Model.PageIndex + 1) })%>

        <% }
           else
           { %>    
           next
        <%} %>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

**The Error I get:**

```
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
'System.Web.Mvc.Html.HtmlExtensions.ActionLinkImage(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, string, string, object, object)'
 and
'System.Web.Mvc.Html.HtmlExtensions.ActionLinkImage(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, string, string, object, object)'
\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\3ICMS\Views\Articles\Index.aspx   111 
------
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
'System.Web.Mvc.Html.HtmlExtensions.ActionLinkImage(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, string, string, object, object)'
'System.Web.Mvc.Html.HtmlExtensions.ActionLinkImage(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, string, string, object, object)'
\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\3ICMS\Views\Articles\Index.aspx   116 
------
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
'System.Web.Mvc.Html.HtmlExtensions.ActionLinkImage(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, string, string, object, object)' 
and
'System.Web.Mvc.Html.HtmlExtensions.ActionLinkImage(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, string, string, object, object)' 
\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\3ICMS\Views\Articles\Index.aspx   106 
------
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
'System.Web.Mvc.Html.HtmlExtensions.ActionLinkImage(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, string, string, object, object)' and
'System.Web.Mvc.Html.HtmlExtensions.ActionLinkImage(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, string, string, object, object)' 
\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\3ICMS\Views\Articles\Index.aspx   101
```

Comment: Try using Fully Qualified names to call the methods. E.g. AdminDLL.ClassName / Instance.MethodName

Comment: @Teresko, I have mentioned the error msg below the code

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have 2 different versions of the System.Web.Mvc dll referenced somehow and it doesn't know which to call.

Comment: Everything got solved...The site was opened as a Website on a new machine and not as a Project Solution.I think the problem is in Website mode multiple .dll files are created when complied but in Project Solution only single .dll file is created and hence all ambiguous problems gets solved.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion will be to remove any reference of System.Web.MVC from `'theSiteCMS'` (since `'theSite.dll'` already  contains it) and then add `theSiteDLL` as *project referece*.

I am assumming both of them are inside the same solution file. I hope this helps.