# The call is ambiguous between the following EXACT IDENTICAL methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I've been using the ASP.NET MVC library TwitterBootstrapMVC (https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com) for a while.
I had to reinstall the packages and all the sudden I started seeing the following error whever I use the html helpers in my views:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
>   'TwitterBootstrap3.BootstrapHtmlExtension.Bootstrap(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper)'
>   and
>   'TwitterBootstrap3.BootstrapHtmlExtension.Bootstrap(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper)'

The thing that stuns me is the fact that it tells me that the call is ambiguous between the EXACT SAME 2 methods. That does not seem to make any sense to me AT ALL.

I have cleaned my solution, reinstalled the packages multiple times etc. and nothing seems to remove the "ambiguous" error.

Do anyone know what could be the issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521396/the-call-is-ambiguous-between-the-following-methods-or-properties

Comment: @DerekTomes
Thanks. I followed the solutions of the thread and I solved my issue :)